# Password not accepted at login

Tags: login, password, pam, kerberos

I had tried to setup kerberos authentication to log into some ADS thing at my new university, however that didn't work and resulted in me having to enter my password twice for everything.

So I did: `sudo apt-get remove libpam-krb5`

Then some authentication tool came up asking if I wanted to ignore local changes(?) to which I entered yes. Then I restarted, now I can't login.

I tried to do recovery mode and enter into the root prompt, but apparently it is in read-only mode.

Comment: To rescue your document you can boot with a live Linux assuming you did not encrypt your home folder (or whatever drive where you put your work.)

Answer (score -1):

In recovery mode try making the root directory writable:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /
```